# How can I extract human-readable configuration information from a Cisco AnyConnect installer?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I am an academic and I am in the middle of moving universities. My new employer does not provide "human readable" information about their preferred Cisco AnyConnect VPN configuration settings, unlike my old institution, which did. I much prefer using my own clients for this; they're more configurable, better, and can be set to do useful (for me) things such as caching passwords. They  also don't have "telemetry", which I don't want to give my employer access to on devices that I own.

If I have the Cisco AnyConnect vpn client binaries, how can I extract configuration settings in a human-readable form? i note that the client contains:

- `AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xsd` -- a human-readable set of client-specific configuration strings, written in XML
- `AnyConnectLocalPolicy.xml` -- also a human-readable set of highly uninformative client-specific strings, none of which contain connection information
- `ACManifestVPN.xml` -- a very short file containing three keys, which appear to paths to (and names of) the VPN client itself
- `ConfigParam.bin`. This is a binary file that is exceptionally short, containing information that appears to be either obsfucated or compressed with an unknown algorithm and no magic bytes at the start (0x01 0x6C)
- `VPNManifest.dat`. Similarly, another short binary file starting with almost entirely 0s and containing a version number and the string "VPNCore" that matches up with the client version.

Is it possible to find out more information about this, and de-obsfucate the information without, e.g. Ghidra?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Gateway (hostname) of the VPN server, you can follow the procedure as [explained on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/154797/1175982).

Then using the GUI, open network manager, add connection, choose VPN / openconnect like Cisco Anyconnect

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1104721)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question – in order to use the gui for openconnect you need to know what the server details are; precompiled packages of anyconnect explicitly hide this from the user. I ended up answering my question by a mixture of decompiling the binary's parsing of its text files in radare2 and a lot of sleuthing.